# Working with search bar on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have a `cities` array that I want the user the add.

On the `add screen` I want that when the user start typing, the options for the cities (from the array) will be displayed in a table view.

I've searched on the internet for hours but everything seems to be old and not up-to-date (apple deprecated some things in iOS 8 and 9).

I'm searching for an up-to-date tutorial on how to do it, anyone can help?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a tutorial.   eg http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/01/08/ios-quick-tip-filtering-a-uitableview-with-a-search-bar/   If its not working, tell us what you are trying and where the problem is.   eg... initWithStyle on cell was removed so I can't do this thing.   Whatever.   Show us what you have so we can help.   Include the source code and/or screen shots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I may clarify..., do you want to search/filter on the cities array?

Either way, this is the way I do it with UISearchController in iOS9.

0) You need these protocols (if it's a tableView):

```
@interface YourViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating>
```

1) Declare these properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *searchResults;
```

3) in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (!_searchController.searchBar.superview) {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    }
    if (!self.searchController.active && self.searchController.searchBar.text.length == 0) {
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.searchController.searchBar.frame));
    }
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (self.searchController.isActive) {
        self.searchController.active = NO;
    }
}
```

3) Getter/Setters for the searchController:

```
#pragma mark - Getters / Setters

- (UISearchController *)searchController {
    if (!_searchController) {
        _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
        _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
        _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
        _searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
        [_searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    }
    return _searchController;
}

- (NSArray *)searchResults {
    NSString *searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
    if (searchString.length > 0) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString];
        return [self.cities filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    }
    else {
        return self.cities;
    }

    return @[];
}
```

4) Update tableView:

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 if (self.searchController.isActive && self.searchController.searchBar.text.length > 0) {
            return self.searchResults.count;
        }
        else {
           return self.cities.count;
        }         
  return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSString *cityName = @"";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (self.searchController.isActive && (![self.searchController.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""])) {
            cityName = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else {
            cityName = [self.cities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        ((YourTableViewCell *)cell).cityNameLabel.text = cityName;
      }
     return cell;
    }
```

5) Update UISearchControllerDelegate

```
#pragma mark - UISearchControllerDelegate

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Anyways, that's the jist of it. Good luck. There's plenty of tutorials on this as well.

Comment: Thank you! But for some reason the search is very slow and the UI freezes for a few seconds. "citiesArray" is really big so maybe that is the problem (86,111 objects), but how can I make it load faster? Or at least to make the UI be smoother and not to freeze? Thank you!

Comment: Hm.. I'm sorry I don't think I can help you there, cause I've never ran into this problem as my arrays has been very small. Your array being really large definitely contributes to the problem, but I wouldn't know how to fix it. :-/

Comment: It's perfectly working. But while searching the name into Array of the dictionary, it was not showing any result. So for array of dictionary, I changed the predicate: `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString];
`
that is 'name' keyword of Dic value