# UISearchBar with NSArray (searching in UITableView not work)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, crash, searchbar

I would like to search in my UITableView by keeping the images next to the text. I can not understand the problem, I say that the crash happens as soon as you type text.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (isSearching) {
        return [filteredContentList count];
    }
    else {
        return [contentList count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (isSearching) {
        NSDictionary *searchResult = [filteredContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *uppercaseString = [[searchResult objectForKey:@"title"] uppercaseString];
        cell.nameLabel.text = uppercaseString;

        NSString *stringImage = [searchResult valueForKeyPath:@"thumbnail.file"];

        [cell.parallaxImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringImage]
                              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        [cell.parallaxImage setShowActivityIndicatorView:YES];
        [cell.parallaxImage setIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    }
    else {
        NSDictionary *searchResult = [contentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *uppercaseString = [[searchResult objectForKey:@"title"] uppercaseString];
        cell.nameLabel.text = uppercaseString;

        NSString *stringImage = [searchResult valueForKeyPath:@"thumbnail.file"];

        [cell.parallaxImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringImage]
                              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        [cell.parallaxImage setShowActivityIndicatorView:YES];
        [cell.parallaxImage setIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    }

    return cell;

}

- (void)searchTableList {
    NSLog(@"title");

    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];

    filteredContentList = [contentList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSLog(@"filtered : %@", filteredContentList);
}

#pragma mark - Search Implementation

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearching = YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"Text change - %d",isSearching);

    //Remove all objects first.
    //[filteredContentList removeAllObjects];

    [self searchTableList];
    if([searchText length] != 0) {
        isSearching = YES;
        [self searchTableList];
    }
    else {
        isSearching = NO;
    }
    [self.tblContentList reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Search Clicked");

    [self searchTableList];
}
```

(in my code the NSPredicate are fully functional, but I have a crash :)

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/UITableView.m:8174
2017-04-22 10:24:59.538 TableSearch[13649:2676593] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UISearchResultsTableView: 0x7d444000; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7de362c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7de35f50>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {375, 1936}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<ViewController: 0x7dc37b00>)'
*** First throw call stack:
/////////

/////////
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see from the crash report, the problem is within `[UISearchResultsTableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]`. Did you override this method? If so, could you specify the code for it as well?

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev All my code is on, I miss something?

Comment: 1st - One small suggestion: since you have two states, searching and not, and the setup of the cells is identical, you can just so something like:

NSArray * datasource = isSearching?  filteredContentList : contentList;

And then use the data source to configure the cell. This will reduce the amount of code you have.

2nd a question: did you call [tableView reloadData] when you switch between searching and not searching?

Comment: Here is the solution, please check the link. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503790/working-with-search-bar-on-ios-9>

Answer (score 0):

**//Better use two arrays**

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        isSeraching = false;
            [_tableView reloadData];
    }else{

        isSeraching = true;

 NSString *searchString = searchBar.text;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString];
            [filteredArray addObjects:[searchArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
    [_tableView reloadData];

    }


}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (isSeraching) {
        return searchArray.count;
    }else{
        return filteredArray.count;
    }
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (isSeraching) {

        SearchNewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchCell"];
        cell.searchingLabel.text = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;

    }else{

    RTSearchRecentViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"recentSearch" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.recentTextLabel.text = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this method:

```
TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

as it can return `nil`.

You should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, which ensures an instantiated cell in all cases:

```
TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

That exception is telling you that `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returned `nil`, but it shouldn't.